# django restful api - how to serialize foreign keys

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django 1.8 with djangorestframework==3.6.3.
I took the model examples from the documentation:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield

Here are my serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')


class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration', 'album')
```

and here is how I call the serializer:

```
def index(request):
    if Track.objects.all().count() == 0:
        album = Album.objects.create(album_name='something', artist='John')
        Track.objects.create(album=album, order=1, title='something', duration=1)

    print TrackSerializer(instance=Track.objects.all()[0]).data
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

The print statement give me:
{'duration': 1, 'album': 1, 'order': 1, 'title': u'something'}
Why is it not giving me all the field data for the corresponding album?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the corresponding example, they've used to return the **`Album`**'s data whereas you are trying to return/print **`Track`**'s data.
So, if you try as below, it will print/return the data as described/shown in the DRF doc

```
def index(request):
    if Track.objects.all().count() == 0:
        album = Album.objects.create(album_name='something', artist='John')

        print(AlbumSerializer(album).data)  # this will print the data as explianed in the doc

        Track.objects.create(album=album, order=1, title='something', duration=1)

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

---

If you want to show the details realted to **`album`**, create a new album serializer, **`AlbumNewSerializer`** and link it in `TrackSerializer`
as,

```
class AlbumNewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist')


class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album = AlbumNewSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration', 'album')
```

---

**NOTE**: You could use **`AlbumSerializer`** instead of **`AlbumNewSerializer`**, but the result maybe in a ugly nested fashion (not tested..)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album = AlbumSerializer(…)

    ...
```